# SQL query in classic asp using ma access as databse

Tags: asp-classic

Here is the statement of select query.. I am getting error as:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14' 
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause.

```
Dim DataConn
Set DataConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DataConn.Open "Driver={Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)}; DBQ="& Server.Mappath("db\wsmt.mdb") & ";pwd=openreach;"

Dim Recordset_report
Set Recordset_report = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Dim sRet

if Request.form("submit1")<>"" then

    Recordset_report.Open "Select WP.CR_No as ""Cr No"", WP.WP_ID as""WP ID"", WP_Name as ""WP Name"","&_
" iif(isnull(ow1),' ',ow1+';')+' '+' '+iif(isnull(ow2),' ',ow2+';')+' '+' '+iif(isnull(ow3),' ',ow3+';')+' '+' '+iif(isnull(ow4),' ',ow4+';')+' '+' '+iif(isnull(ow5),' ',ow5) as ""Owner(s)"","&_
"Type as ""WP Type"", Release, Area, Rec_dt as ""Date Started"", Rec_from as ""Requirement Owner"","&_
"TCD,Perc_comp as ""% Completed"", Complexity, Status,Act_close as ""Actual Closed Date"" from wp, "&_

" inner join ( select wp_id,owner1,(select fullname from userinfo where userid=a.owner1) as ow1,owner2,"&_
" (select fullname from userinfo where userid=a.owner2) as ow2,owner3,"&_
" (select fullname from userinfo where userid=a.owner3) as ow3,owner4,"&_
" (select fullname from userinfo where userid=a.owner4) as ow4,owner5,"&_
" (select fullname from userinfo where userid=a.owner5) as ow5 from allocation a) as t,"&_
" on (wp.wp_id = t.wp_id) where Rec_dt >= #"&Request.form("from")&"# and "&_
" Rec_dt <= #"&Request.form("to")&"#  and not WP.Disable order by Rec_dt, "&_ 

" inner join (select tool_est,wp_id from estimation), "&_
" on (wp.wp_id = Estimation.wp_id) where Rec_dt >= #"&Request.form("from")&"# and ,"&_
" Rec_dt <= #"&Request.form("to")&"#  and not WP.Disable order by Rec_dt ", DataConn
```

Answer (score 3):

you're doing "`from wp, inner join`" => must remove the ","
after better reviewing it you have more situations where you are implying "," where you shouldn't. Gonna try to point out a few, but you should review the query.

You need to remove the ",":
`as t, on (wp.wp_id = t.wp_id)`

Also, after your order by `order by Rec_dt` you have:
`, inner join (select tool_est,wp_id from estimation), on`
The "," before the inner join and the one before the on both need to be removed. Also, in the line before the last one you have `and ,` this comma two should be removed.

Lastly, your last inner join shouldn't be where it is, but I still didn't got to a conclusion wether you really want a inner join in there or if it should be worked out to some kind of union.